Completeness of Y (normed tvs) in the proof of th. 2 in ch. V section 3 of Yosida's Functional Analysis ed 6
I'm stuck on the proof of theorem 2 in chapter V, section 3 of Yosida's Functional Analysis edition 6 (pages 140,141).
Theorem 2 says : A locally convex linear topological space X is reflexive iff it is a barrel space and every closed, convex, balanced and bounded set of X is compact in the weak topology of X.
In the last part of the proof, the author considers the set $Y=\bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} nK$ where $K$ is a closed, convex and balanced and (by hypothesis) compact in the weak topology of X. He shows (very rapidly indeed) that Y is made a normed space if one uses the Minkowsky functional associated with K.
The point that I don't understand is the following: "Y is a B-space since K is w-compact".
Actually K is weakly compact in the original topology of X but I cannot show that it is weakly compact in the topology of the normed space Y, so cannot show completeness of Y.

Try to prove the following lemma: Let $(Y,|\cdot|)$ be a normed space whose unit ball $K$ is compact in some coarser Hausdorff vector space topology $\tau$ on $Y$. Then the norm is complete.

@Jochen I think I've found a way to show this though it is not easy. I check the details before sharing.

Perhaps this will help proving the above lemma

My first attempt, as noted by @Jochen, was flawed. Here is a (hopefully) correct solution:
Let us denote by $\tau$ the topology on $Y$ induced by the weak topology on $X$ and by $\tau_1$ the norm topology on $Y$ (induced by the Minkowski functional of $K$). We want to prove that all $\tau_1$ Cauchy sequences are actually $\tau_1$-convergent. Assume $x_n$ is a Cauchy sequence in $(Y,\tau_1)$.
Claim 1. $x_n$ converges in $\tau$.
Proof: Since Cauchy sequences are bounded, we can assume without loss of generality that $x_n\in K$ for all $n$. Clearly, $x_n$ is a Cauchy sequence in $Y,\tau$ as well and by $\tau-$compactness of $K$ there exists $x\in K$ such that $x_n\overset{\tau}\to x$.
Claim 2. $x_n\overset{\tau_1}\to x$.
Proof: Let $B$
be a small closed ball centered in $0$. By Cauchy-ness of $x_n$, we know that there exists $n_0$ such that for any $n>n_0$, $x_n\in B+x_{n_0}=:\tilde B$. Since $\tilde B$ is $\tau-$cpt, it follows that $x\in \tilde B$, hence $x_n\in 2B+x$, which proves that $x_n$ $\tau_1-$converges to $x$ since $B$ was taken to be arbitrarily small.

If you mean by $|\cdot|$ the Minkowski functional of $K$ then the identical map $(Y,|\cdot|)\to (Y,\tau)$ is continuous but not the other way round.

@Jochen Yes, you are correct. I had implicitly (and mistakenly) assumed $K$ to be a nbhd of $0$, which of course makes the proof rather trivial.

@Pelota Your proof is much shorter than the one I've worked out. I'm wondering if it would be possible to make it even shorter, replacing Claim 1 by the fact that $x_n$ has a $\tau$-accumulation point $x \in K$ (that happens to be in $\tilde B$ by $\tau$-compacity).

@Ptony Sure, but the proof you get is not really shorter: after all, if you prove accumulation you only need to notice that cauchy in stronger topology implies Cauchy in weaker, which is trivial. But you are right in that you don't actually need convergence in $\tau$ for point $2$. It's a matter of taste, ultimately.
